# CodeIgniter 3.0 app on a subdomain

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with CodeIgniter 3, I have a project on a subdomain, the big problem that occurs to me is that after loguearme page freezes into an infinite loop.

`mipagina.dominio.com.mx` page is in the file paths to set the default `controller $ route ['default_controller'] = 'user / login';` if I get access, but after loving me or giving access logear page stays in a loop.

For example, logeo after me must send `mipagina.dominio.com.mx/admin/index`, but not that reason the URL gives me `mipagina.dominio.com.mx/?admin/index` and hence does not pass, it stays in the loop.

(Sorry not English, used a translator).

Comment: yes, sorry i don´t know ingles, but the problem was fixed, the problem was an code line in he file Config.php is this  line 
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
and was 
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;   :D

Comment: How do I add?  How do I add?

Comment: There are quite a lot of features to learn around the site, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

The problem was fixed, the problem was a code line in the file Config.php is this line `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;` and was `$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;`.